# How to merge rows based on identical content of column, where the rest of columns are categorical

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe that looks more or less like that:

```
df<-tibble(segments=c('Hello','Hello', 'Hello', 'Block', 'Block', 'Hi', 'Hi', 'Hi'),
          year=c(2015, 2015,2015,2017, 2017, 2015,2015,2015),
          Colour=c('Yellow', NA,NA, 'Pink', NA, NA, 'Green', NA),
          Eval=c(NA, 'Yes',NA, NA, 'No', 'No', NA, NA),
          Ball=c(NA, NA, 'A', NA, NA, NA,NA, 'B'))
```

I want to merge rows so that each row cprrespond to one segment and looks like that:

```
df1<-tibble(segments= c('Hello', 'Block', 'Hi'),
       year=c(2015, 2017, 2015),
       Colour=c('Yellow', 'Pink', 'Green'),
       Eval=c('Yes', 'No', 'No'),
       Ball=c('A', 'B', NA))
```

Because variables are not numerical I can't merge with a group_by /summarise all.
The only thing I know of the dataframe, is that per each 'grouped segments' there is a maximmum of one value per column, the rest being NAs.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: “Because variables are not numerical I can't merge with a group_by /summarise all.” — Yes you can, `group_by`/`summarize` has no such restriction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
library(dplyr)# version >= 1.1.0
df %>%
   reframe(across(Colour:Ball, ~ .x[!is.na(.x)][1]), 
   .by = c(segments, year))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 5
  segments  year Colour Eval  Ball 
  <chr>    <dbl> <chr>  <chr> <chr>
1 Hello     2015 Yellow Yes   A    
2 Block     2017 Pink   No    <NA> 
3 Hi        2015 Green  No    B
```

---

Or

```
df %>%
   group_by(segments, year) %>% 
   summarise(across(everything(),  ~ .x[!is.na(.x)][1]), .groups = "drop")
```

Comment: Or `... %>% summarise(across(everything(), ~ first(na.omit(.x)))`